# How to run C .exe file in auto run by USB?

Tags: autorun

I have a c program(i.e .exe) , i want to execute that program through USB in auto run mode, when USB is on then file should run . I make it auto run file i.e autorun.inf .Inside auto run file the content is 
[autorun] action=v1.exe open=v1.exe

but it is not working .

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using? I thought auto run was disabled in windows 7. See : http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2009/04/28/autorun-changes-in-windows-7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Read this if you are using win 7 [AutoRun changes in Windows 7](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2009/04/28/autorun-changes-in-windows-7.aspx)

more over this kind of activity is using by malware so try to avoid, otherwise you will loos your trust level.